# how to reload maps from db when split brain occurs due to network partitioning in hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

I am using hazelcast 3.2.2 community edition.

I am performing various tests with hazelcast. I have two separate VMs which are running two hazelcast instances as linux service forming a single cluster. I will refer them as HAZ-A and HAZ-B in this context.

Here is the test flow (`link` means `Physical link` in this context):

1) `HAZ-A is up, HAZ-B is up.`

2) `Link down of HAZ-A, HAZ-B link is up.`

Perform some operations say change password of a user, so HAZ-B will have two versions of user object (One will be backup of HAZ-A say version 1, another will be updated copy say version 2).

3) `Link down of HAZ-B, HAZ-A link is already down. Hence links of both HAZ-A and HAZ-B are down.`

4) `Restore link of HAZ-A. Link is already down of HAZ-B.`

Perform some operations say change password of a user, at this time I am getting `stale` data, since HAZ-A did not get a single chance to sync with HAZ-B.

**So the point here is:**

> Can we implement/inject any kind of listener which will detect
>   interface up/down or link up/down and upon detection we can simply
>   re-sync data from db ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation it seems both HAZ-A and HAZ-B will load the values from the DB and when they eventually see each other, they will merge

From Chapter 18

> If a MapStore was in use, those lost partitions would be reloaded from some database, making each mini-cluster complete. Each mini-cluster will then recreate the missing primary partitions and continue to store data in them, including backups on the other nodes.